# How do i make a cell using variables? using VB script in Excel 2007

Tags: vbscript, excel-2007

I am working on a project which requires me check for the last used row in the spreadsheet and then extract data from a range of cells from another spreadsheet after this last used row in a cell (i.e. A10 etc.)

The problem is that i know which column name from the current spreadsheet to use for importing data (i.e column A), but is there a way to assign the row number and make a cell which looks like "A". The last used  keeps changing as the last row used keeps changing as we add data.

Here is the current code to maybe better explain myself:

```
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

`CurrRow = LastRow + 1`

`ExtractExcelToArray wsDCCTabA.Range("C15:C25") ' Extracting from here`

`ExportAccesstoExcel wsTempGtoS.Range("E&CurrRow:E12") 'importing into current spreadsheet code here`

As you can see, i tried using something like "E&CurrRow" but it doesnt seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ExportAccesstoExcel wsTempGtoS.Range("E" & CurrRow & ":E12")
```